# Bootstrap 3 place 2 columns in right side

Tags: html, css, col

I'm trying to make my two columns placed on the right side but when I add float left in my class the second column was ahead from my first column.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 3%;">
                <div class="row">
                    
                        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12" style="float: right;">
                            <p>Filter by: </p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="float: right;">
                            <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for hotels" />
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                                <li><a>All Hotels </a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                              </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
```

How can I make the first column ahead from the second col? Thanks!

Comment: What is your desired goal in the end? Should both columns be stacked or it's text right aligned? If you just want both of them to be on the right side with another column left, then just use a two-column grid with a sub-grid on the right side.

Comment: You don't need `float:right`, you can [offset](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) the columns , or use auto margin. Moreover, if you want, why not just swap the content of the two columns so that the *first column content* is in the right-most side

Comment: @CarlBinalla Auto margin is a feature of Bootstrap 4 if I remember rightly.

Comment: @Andreas You're right, although what's stopping OP from just using `margin-left:auto` or `margin-right:auto`?